# How do I prescroll an element in django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a scrollable element that I would like to be pre-scrolled by 320px on loading the page in my django calendar project. Can I achieve that without using javascript and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty div where you want the page to scroll:

```
<div id="#scroll_here"></div>
```

Or give the element you want to scroll to an id.

Then if you append `#scroll_here` to your `url`, the page will automatically scroll to the element with that id.

For example: `https://example.com/#scroll_here`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's scroll function on the onload event on body to scroll to specific number of pixels horizontally or vertically when your body element loads.

```html
<body onload="window.scroll(0, 320)">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis rutrum nunc, nec fermentum leo lacinia eu. Praesent quis tellus tortor. Donec varius sagittis tellus, at pellentesque libero volutpat vitae. Aliquam rhoncus neque tellus, sed vehicula
  purus aliquet vel. Sed auctor volutpat risus tincidunt luctus. Nam suscipit diam sed urna iaculis, sit amet viverra magna convallis. Proin egestas nisi eget nisl laoreet, ut sagittis purus molestie. Nullam sed eros et quam pulvinar venenatis vel et
  nisl. Aliquam non nunc quis enim consectetur fermentum. Pellentesque elementum commodo nunc. Aliquam sed tempus nisl, in fermentum sapien. Morbi semper condimentum sagittis. Pellentesque iaculis in lacus vel vehicula. Quisque luctus elit ipsum, et iaculis
  leo lacinia eu. Duis et ex leo. Quisque pharetra vel ex ac sodales. Proin tincidunt at lacus sed scelerisque. Nunc ultricies condimentum congue. Aenean auctor dolor id diam lacinia pellentesque. Vestibulum lobortis eros cursus condimentum bibendum.
  Curabitur nisi dui, dictum non vestibulum sed, viverra nec tellus. Sed ornare nunc a nibh tincidunt, quis sagittis justo semper. Proin venenatis eros quis tortor ultricies mattis. Suspendisse malesuada consectetur aliquet. Donec suscipit massa dolor,
  pretium mollis nibh rutrum ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus venenatis, ipsum non volutpat semper, purus arcu dignissim leo, sed suscipit quam arcu sit amet ipsum. Morbi ut facilisis eros. Nam id cursus massa. Nulla et ultricies leo. Sed aliquam vitae
  dolor id egestas. Aenean pretium leo at libero condimentum, sit amet finibus ex iaculis. Nulla venenatis magna et leo laoreet egestas. Quisque lobortis justo sed lacus condimentum, in rhoncus felis pulvinar. Vestibulum consectetur auctor orci vitae
  viverra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse posuere, eros id iaculis pellentesque, tortor lectus gravida tortor, vitae lacinia risus nunc eu ipsum. Maecenas blandit ex eget pharetra porta. Integer scelerisque rhoncus
  lobortis. Mauris lectus sem, tristique varius eros sed, congue imperdiet leo. Morbi pretium, magna non scelerisque dapibus, libero nibh malesuada ex, vitae tempor orci ligula ut ligula. Donec eleifend facilisis nisi, vitae consectetur mi. Cras sit amet
  arcu suscipit, porta orci sit amet, lacinia ligula. Nunc dictum tortor quis magna ornare mollis. In metus diam, auctor vitae eros ac, efficitur condimentum felis. Morbi bibendum justo ligula, eget fringilla lacus consectetur eget. Praesent vestibulum
  neque turpis, id efficitur odio vestibulum a. Donec viverra quis quam sit amet aliquam. Nunc non mollis arcu. Maecenas nec tincidunt libero, dapibus pretium augue. Proin id bibendum tellus. Pellentesque mollis non velit a auctor. Quisque eu urna metus.
  Fusce a risus eu tellus dapibus mollis eu quis nunc. Etiam dictum lacus vitae leo bibendum hendrerit. Donec non hendrerit libero. Vivamus finibus lorem ac augue ultricies, ut volutpat mi pulvinar. Etiam semper congue vehicula. Donec feugiat sit amet
  arcu a cursus. Ut blandit lectus a euismod viverra. Vivamus feugiat rutrum consequat. Donec purus libero, bibendum sed aliquet sed, tristique non nunc. Ut non leo at tellus ultrices sodales et a felis. Aliquam quis augue ex. Phasellus tristique, nisi
  quis dignissim egestas, nulla quam egestas massa, ut imperdiet turpis nisi vitae lacus. Etiam justo augue, aliquam euismod aliquet sed, pretium non libero. Nunc id semper sapien. Donec mollis, nunc nec dapibus dignissim, felis eros mattis enim, vulputate
  porta augue est eget leo. Fusce imperdiet ex eu cursus mollis. Donec varius leo ac urna pellentesque, nec gravida elit suscipit. Praesent euismod venenatis lectus ut commodo. Etiam hendrerit, nisl quis eleifend rhoncus, justo est ultricies massa, et
  sodales urna nisi eget nisl. Suspendisse dui sem, luctus aliquet vestibulum non, dictum a nisi. Sed nec augue sed lectus fringilla finibus at at sapien. Etiam sed libero malesuada, mattis nisl nec, hendrerit quam. Nam pharetra felis id purus dapibus
  semper. Suspendisse tincidunt commodo lectus non malesuada. Praesent tristique nulla nec varius dapibus. Nulla vel interdum massa. Aenean quis mauris id neque lacinia porttitor consequat non libero. Vivamus sed erat quis lorem consectetur vestibulum.
  Pellentesque hendrerit leo in eros facilisis pharetra. Mauris sed quam id orci elementum maximus at vel turpis. Cras in ex eget libero varius mollis. Quisque mi nunc, hendrerit ac consectetur nec, semper sit amet sapien. Sed finibus varius turpis, nec
  lacinia leo cursus quis. Integer at rutrum velit, euismod semper elit. Ut faucibus malesuada laoreet. Vestibulum in leo sagittis, dignissim elit ut, egestas elit. Ut et lacus in lacus rhoncus malesuada. Maecenas blandit est dui, at interdum ante cursus
  id. Phasellus ligula eros, scelerisque tincidunt imperdiet nec, ultricies ut ligula. Phasellus pellentesque accumsan consequat. Mauris enim ex, posuere at mauris eu, semper dictum nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce
  eu magna et urna pretium scelerisque ac at erat. Duis at leo eleifend, rutrum nulla vitae, pulvinar diam. Quisque condimentum nulla sed purus tempor, id malesuada ex pulvinar. Duis sagittis, elit eu venenatis varius, nunc risus vehicula tortor, a pharetra
  ex dolor at nunc. Quisque lobortis et velit id sagittis. Integer pellentesque, metus vel tempor bibendum, diam tortor dignissim ex, in laoreet tortor ligula id metus. Sed iaculis blandit semper. Nunc tincidunt justo eget eros laoreet ultrices. Donec
  purus diam, rutrum ac elit lacinia, interdum dignissim nibh. Ut scelerisque est eget diam ullamcorper interdum. Proin sed est sit amet ipsum rutrum placerat nec ac ante. Ut sollicitudin est ac quam ultrices, sed semper leo iaculis. Praesent non ante
  ut lacus scelerisque eleifend. Nulla facilisi.
</body>
```